# Breaking points are ignored when using 'doLast' in Gradle tasks

Tags: kotlin, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

In a Kotlin + Gradle + IntelliJ project, I noticed that I can run \ debug (hitting breakpoints) my Main class using one of following tasks defined in gradle.build:

```
// debug works!!
task debugTest1(type:JavaExec) {
    group = "Execution"
    description = "Run the main class with JavaExecTask"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "temp.Main"
}

// debug works!
task debugTest2() {
    javaexec{
        group = "Execution"
        description = "Run the main class with JavaExecTask"
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        main = "temp.Main"
    }
}
```

However, when adding 'doLast', the debug in IntelliJ runs but ignores breakpoints:

```
// debug ignores breakpoint!
task debugTest3() {
    doLast {
        javaexec{
            group = "Execution"
            description = "Run the main class with JavaExecTask"
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
            main = "temp.Main"
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle file is similar to this

```
plugins {
    //id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.4.20-RC"
}

group 'MY-COMPANY-GROUP'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    compileJava { options.encoding = "UTF-8" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
}
```

My temp.Main file (Main.kt):

```
@file:JvmName("Main")

package temp


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
    Object.setProperties();
    print("Object.setProperties() = ${Object.property1}")
}
```

I first came to this problem working in a project using Cucumber, Gradle and Kotlin. All my breakpoints are ignored in this project too. The task declaration in that project is as follows (based on Cucumber's documentation):

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, testClasses
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = [/*'--plugin','pretty', */
                    '--glue', 'COMPANY-PACKAGE.cucumber.steps', 'src/test/resources/features',
                    '--tags','not @inProgress']
        }
    }
}
```

My specs are:

- Java: 11
- OS: Windows 10
- Intellij: IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3, October 6th build

Comment: Probably related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-253394